# Adding new WYSIWYG text style or format

Tags: cms, wysiwyg, page-builder

I would like to add a new WYSIWYG text style, similar to the below image.

[image]

As per the official documentation, I have managed to add a new style called "Introductory Paragraph": https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/wysiwyg/configure-tinymce-editor.html

...by adding an adminhtml di.xml:

```
<type name="Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Wysiwyg\DefaultConfigProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="additionalSettings" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="style_formats" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="introductory-paragraph" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Introductory Paragraph</item>
                    <item name="classes" xsi:type="string">introductory-paragraph</item>
                </item>
            </item>
      </argument>
  </arguments>
</type>
```

I've also added a new class `.introductory-paragraph` to my frontend CSS.

The new option is being added to the admin select field. However, no classes are being applied, and when I select it, it doesn't change the HTML at all.

Which other modifications would I need to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps to add your custom style for storefront.

1.Create a new file on this path with name _default.less
For e.g
Source/app/design/frontend/{your theme name}/base/Magento_PageBuilder/web/css/source/content-type/text/_default.less

2. Add your css style

//  custom style for pagebuilder text component

[data-content-type='text'] {
overflow-wrap: break-word;
word-wrap: break-word;

```
h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 2rem;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
h4 {
    font-size: 1rem;
}
h5 {
    font-size: 0.75rem;
}
```

}

3. Run Grunt or your less complier
4. Cache clean/Flush